# match_mapping_type, target only arrays of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a default mapping for my indexes.

I want my array of objects being automatically detected as **`nested`** fields. I want only the array of objects being map as such and not regular objects:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  // someArray should be mapped as a nested type field
  "someArray": [
    {
      "bla": "Blou"
    }
  ],
  // someObject should be mapped as a normal object
  "someObject": {
    "btch": "lasagna"
  }
}
```

In order to try something, here is what I sent to my cluster:

```
PUT _template/automatic_nested_object
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "*", 
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": { 
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is **`"match_mapping_type": "object"`**, matches all the objects and not only the arrays and I can't find anything in the documentation that would allow me to make a difference.

**Does someone know how to make such a difference?**

Comment: How about matching on names? `someArray` would map to `nested` while `someObject` would map to `object`.

Comment: The purpose of my dynamic template is to avoid defining the mapping or caring about the name of the fields :/ So it would not be a solution for me

Comment: I understand that, I was just trying to figure out if you were willing to make some tradeoff and include a "clue" in the field names, that we could use to dynamically map nested arrays.

Comment: But according to this documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html it would be the only solution..

Comment: Hence why I'm suggesting it :-)

Comment: Meh, you should add it as a response then, I would validate it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to add some clue in the field name so that you know which fields you want to dynamically map as nested:

```
PUT _template/automatic_nested_object
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "*", 
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {                      <--- note: _default_ deprecated in ES6
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "match": "*Array",    <--- name clue for nested array
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```